How to measure gate driver power losses?
I would like to measure losses of the Infineon 1ED3124MC12H gate driver.
To test this component, I created the following circuit, in which the 2.2nF capacitor corresponds to the gate-source capacitor of the MOSFET that will be used.

My first idea was to measure the current icc2 and iee2, then calculate a power:
pcc2 = icc2 * vcc2 and pee2 = iee2 * vee2
So the total power dissipated by the IC should be pcc2 + pee2
Is this correct? Or the power that I calculated doesn't correspond to the power dissipated by the IC?
If it's not correct, how could I measure the power dissipated by the IC?
I didn't take icc1 into consideration because the current is very small.

The power consumed by any system, with any number of pins, is
$$P(t) = \sum_n I_n(t)·V_n(t),$$
where \$n\$ iterates over every pin of the system¹, \$I_n(t)\$ is the current into pin \$n\$, and \$V_n(t)\$ is the voltage at pin \$n\$ relative to an arbitrary (but consistent) reference².
This gives you the instantaneous power \$P(t)\$ as a function of time. It includes any power being stored in inductances or capacitances, which is not dissipated power. But if you take the average of \$P(t)\$ over time--either a sufficiently long time that the error becomes negligible, or an exact multiple of the period--once the system reaches steady-state, this is the dissipated power.
Note that, in general, this just means power that leaves the system, not necessarily power that gets converted into heat. It may leave in the form of mechanical power, light, sound, or something else. In this case, it does represent the total heat production within the gate driver, because no significant amount of any other form of energy is produced.
In your case, as the currents into IN+ and IN- are negligible, and you've said you also consider the current into Vcc1 negligible, you can skip those three pins for an approximation. If you choose GND as your reference voltage (as is the norm), you can also skip that pin; 0 V times anything is still zero. So all that's left are the four pins on the right.
You're left, then, with two choices. If you care about the total power consumption of the whole gate driver system (i.e. including any power dissipated in the gate resistors and in the MOSFET itself), you can leave out the pins OUT+ and OUT-, because they are internal nodes of this composite driver-resistor-capacitor-mosfet system. You will also want to include the effects of the 100n capacitors, which you can do by just measuring the current where you've drawn instead of directly at the driver's pins. This leads directly to the equation you proposed: \$P(t) = V_{cc2}(t)·I_{cc2}(t) + V_{ee2}(t)·I_{ee2}(t)\$.
If, instead, you care about specifically the power dissipated in the driver chip itself, you should measure all currents and voltages directly at the device pins and be sure to include the OUT+ and OUT- pins. This way, you exclude the effect of external devices and get only the dissipation that leads to heating of the gate driver IC itself, which is what you need for determining heatsink requirements.

¹ A "pin" here is an externally-exposed node of the system; no internal nodes are counted. We're treating the entire system (which may contain more than one device) as a black box.
² If you include the reference voltage in the equations explicitly, it cancels out, so you can just remove it from the equation, as I've done here.
